# Grouping by clause on a string column

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a SQL squery,

```
SELECT * FROM gr_person as GR
INNER JOIN ADDRESS ON GR.address_code = ADDRESS.address_code 
JOIN dbo.GR_PERSON_TYPES GPT
ON GR.person_type = GPT.person_type 
WHERE event_number = '101000008' 
ORDER BY GPT.type_key
```

That returns

```
GR.event_number, GR.person_type, GR.customer_code, GPT.type_key, GPT.event_type, GPT.person_type
101000008          Wife           10001             3             2                 Wife
101000008          Wife           10001             4             3                 Wife
```

I want this query to return only ONE ROW if the GR.PERSON_TYPE is SAME as in this case.

I tried adding a group by GR.PERSON_TYPE, but can't help it.

Can somebody tell me how to do it?

Comment: This will never be just one row, unless you aggregate the other fields (e.g. `type_key`,`event_type`) by either not including them, or combining them into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `person_type` to get one result for the group `Wife`, but you will need to aggregate or exclude your other columns.

For instance, if you only want one record for `Wife`, what should the value for `type_key` and `event_type` be? If you want to see the maximum or average `event_type` for your Wife group, you could use `max(event_type)` or `avg(event_type)`. The documentation for your DBMS should be able to explain all the aggregate functions for you.

Comment: What I did is made two separate queries:
1) for getting all the columns except the GR.PERSON_TYPE
2) select GR.Person_type ONLY

And then pass on these values to my code.

That fixed my bug. Now I dont get multiple values at all. 

Thanks guys anyways. I appreciate it.

This is why I post my questions here. It always helps.

Thanks everyone